# Prevent Eclipse from Adding a Space After Comments

Tags: java, eclipse, doxygen

I am using Doxygen with eclipse for documenting a Java project on which I am working. Currently, the code formatter inserts a space after comments, which creates difficulties for documenting class variables. For example, the following code

```
public class Example {
    /// this is the description of the variable
    public String var = "hellooooo world";
}
```

is "corrected" to

```
public class Example {
    // / this is the description of the variable
    public String var = "hellooooo world";
}
```

which nukes the documentation of the variable I am documenting. Obviously I could simply turn off the code formatter, but it's really useful. I simply am trying to avoid scripts or find/replace calls if possible. I assumed this was a common question, but I have been unable to find anything thus far.

Comment: What about /** The comment block? Look any better?

Comment: That's a solution, but not the most preferable one.

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way is to add a new code style formatter for Java. To do this go to: *preferences -> Java -> Code Style -> Formatter*

Then you'll need to create a new formatter profile (the built-in profile can't be edited). In the new formatter profile window is a tab for comment formatting.

Comment: Thanks for the help. Under the comments tab, I don't see an option for adding spaces to the beginning of comments. Am I missing it?